# Play a .flv via rtmp stream in a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, stream, flv, rtmp

The only way way I figured out to play this kind of stream with existing tools is piping it through rtmpdump into vlc.

The command line for it looks like:

```
rtmpdump.exe -v -r rtmp://cp108475.live.edgefcs.net/live/ard_1_800@15782 --swfsize 927444 --swfhash 6c1be1765187eae0bc9af07d858fae59a0effd3c5b803d08db261ced2c5512bb -q | vlc.exe -
```

I just figured out how to play a .flv from local disk in a winform by using [VlcDotNet library](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/)

But now I'm also looking for a method of playing such a .flv **rtmp stream** in a c# winform.